# how do I restart a single instance winforms application

Tags: c#

I have an application that I restart at 2 am every morning using

`Application.Restart();`

the problem is that a inspection a couple of weeks later shows that there are 6 or so instances running.

I tried to limit the number of instances by using

```
 bool IsOwned;
 Mutex m = new Mutex(true, Name, out IsOwned);
 if (!IsOwned)
         Environment.Exit(0);
```

But this didn't work as for some reason the recently stopped instance was still visible...or at least that's my interpretation and as a result the application didn't reatart.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you hook on application exit event a method that releases the mutex and closes it.

Answer (score 3):

By any chance, are you using multiple threads?  If you don't shut down your background threads, they will keep your process running, even through a call to Application.Restart.

I have pasted in some code below that demonstrates this behavior.  To see it, compile a test project with the code below and run it.  (you will need to put 1 button on the form and assign the click handler that I have defined in the code below).

Start Task Manager, go to the Process tab, and make sure to add the PID (process id) column to the view.

Each time you click the button, the app will restart, but you should see the old process still hung in memory (due to a background thread that was not closed down).

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // start a background thread that will never be exited.
            System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate() { while (true) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); });
            thread.Start();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Restart();
        }
}
```

Assuming that this is your problem, the best way to correct it is to put some kind of a check into your background threads (even a bool flag will do).  Have them check for exited periodically and and exit gracefully when your app shuts down.

Note: you could set the thread's background property to true, and it will be exited automatically, but if you do that, you don't have control over which instruction the thread is executing when it exits, so you can't perform any type of cleanup.  It's best to code your own check.

Answer (score 2):

I have run into this problem in the past, and what I believe the issue was is that the mutex of the running instance getting shutdown was not being released before the mutex of the second instance, starting up was checking for it. To solve this, what I did was provided a means to pass back control to my main form with an indication to restart; so that the Shutdown part of the Restart didn't have to perform any tasks except for exiting.

Answer (score 0):

First off... why do you need to restart an app every day?

I'm guessing theres a better solution than an app that restarts itself at 2 AM every day.

For example, you may have a memory leak... as described in your comment.  Addressing that might be a better place to focus your efforts.  Restarting an app preiodically to avoid a memory leak would be considered by most programmers, including myself, a hack.

Comment: what has that got to do with the question? The fact is I would like to restart every day at 2am.

Comment: The why is important... and I have a feeling thats the first thing most people will wonder.

Comment: @Brad - the why is important because (as with other questions here on SO) sometimes the underlying issue can be addressed making your surface issue moot.  The question is completely legit, though I probably would have posted it in the comments instead of as an actual answer.

Comment: it's a stand alone app displaying real time data from industrial plant in dynamically created grapical objects that connect to various SQL servers. It runs continuously 24/7. After 3 weeks or so it seems that the memory allocated gets too much. I have inspected the paint routines to see if there are resources that are not being disposed of properly but didn’t find anything. In the interim, until I find the real problem it was easiest way to get around a potential out of memory exception.

Comment: See my edit.  I dont think its out of line to suggest addressing the root problem instead of a hack.

Comment: Yeah I see it as a hack as well. I would rather not have to restart the application. But reality is that it is a one off application atached to a large LCD screen sitting on the factory floor and I would like it to run now, not when when i have time to  investigate and fix the root problem. I am however working towards finding the problem.